# How to reduce noise disturbance?

Tags: sound

I live in a flat with neighbours all around me. Sometimes, they complain about noise when I do something noisy. What can I do to reduce the disturbance on my neighbours when I listen to music or watch TV?

I want to keep sound of reasonable quality and intensity, and I don't want to use headphones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cover the door and window with cotton as it will not allow the sound to pass away this concept is also used in the studio also. And you want to implement this properly try to put insulator in wall also .Try some points from [here](http://www.apartmenttherapy.com/how-to-block-bothersome-ambient-noises-191472)

Answer (score 1):

Have things like :

`Carpet, heavy draperies and open-cell foams.` in your place. These things make good sound absorber.

Answer (score 1):

"Reasonable quality and intensity" would not disturb your neighbors. 
When you play your beautiful music through the walls it becomes noise!
You could try fiber egg cartons (if you like eggs), attach to the walls 
with that poster tape that doesn't leave a residue (can't remember the name).
They have been used in radio and recording studios to reduce echo, not sure they would reduce high-volume low frequencies very well though.

Or buy a house with a basement... :>)